# Running maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded the hadoop source code which is of maven project structure. Now I want to run it as a Java application in Eclipse. Is it possible, If it so can any one tell me how?

Comment: :-) do you want to run hadoop on your PC ? usually it runs on clusters etc

Comment: yes...I have installed hadoop as single node cluster

Comment: so if you installed it, what is the question? do you want to debug it using your IDE (Eclipse)?

Comment: yes...I want to debug hadoop using eclipse

Comment: i think you can debug it with "remote debugging". you said you installed hadoop - so config it to enable remote debugging, and config your eclipse to work in remote debugging and connect the two.

Comment: In remote debugging we can debug pig,hive map reduce jobs?

Comment: You need to invest quite a bit more time in reading documentation.  Hadoop is not a typica Java program

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Maven project you need to Import as Maven Project 
File -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Find the directory with the pom.xml file

Comment: Tango...If I imported it as maven project..and run whether I have output in my console

Comment: You will have console output if you are writing to the console. 
you can use some sys.out statements or logging to the console

Comment: I have imported it and whether I have to run it as Run-> Run as->?

Comment: You can run the last configuration. I believe its with F11. I generally use shortcut for running files. In the opened editor press Alt + Shift+ x, J (for java programs)

Comment: when I hit F11 It runs my last run configuration which is of another project

Comment: Yes, you run programs in eclipse "run as", then the configuration is done or you can run Java programs from the editor (class with the main method) with  alt + shift + x, j. And later you have a green button with a white arrow and there you can select the configuration and run it.

Comment: I want to run the imported maven project

Comment: Select the project -> (Right click) -> Run as -> Java application

Comment: but there is no option such as java application. when I right click  Run -> Run As -> maven build(options avail)